# Keras - What is the difference between model.evaluate() and model.predict()

Tags: keras

I have two questions :

1/ What is the difference between model.evaluate() and model.predict() ?

2/ How does Keras calculate each one of them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`model.evaluate` predicts values and computes the loss and all attached metrics to the model over a given dataset. It returns a list containing the loss and metrics in one value.

`model.predict` only predicts the output of the model given inputs from a dataset. `model.predict`'s inner workings are used inside `model.evaluate`, but the output of both is different, as they do not compute the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I am going for `model.predict` in beginning as `model.predict` is executed inside `model.evaluate`. model.predict only predict the output matrix on the basis of the test set as the model directs.

However, `model.evaluate` performs a `model.predict` operation internally and calculate the errors and accuracy depending on supplied parameters at the time of of model compilation. For example

```
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss='categorical_crossentropy',  metrics=['mse','mae','accuracy'])
```

Here I have asked model to supply output `mse`, `mae`, and `accuracy`. But it will not provide anything if we execute `model.predict`except output matrix, and then with respect to output we need to calculate error or accuracy. On the other hand, `model.evaluate` is a compact version which will calculate `mse`, `mae`, and `accuracy` all together and will provide a matrix like

```
[0.2498760256045422,0.015400263790238618,,0.9456890699253224]
```

It's similar like `[mse, mae, accuracy]`

Call is yours, anything you can pickup.